# How can I write an or condition to check substrings in a pythonic way?

Tags: python

I would like to find a more elegant way of coding the next:

```
str_example = "u are my // path"
if '//' in str_example or '/' in str_example:
    do something
```

Comment: If `'/'` is in your string then why you're checking `'//'`?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the problem statement?

Comment: `l = ['x', 'y']; any(s in str_example for s in l)`

Answer (score 5):

use `all()` and `any()` functions

```py
str_example = "u are my // path"
if any(s in str_example for s in ['//', '/']):
    pass
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all

Answer (score 3):

You can store the substrings in an array and use something like :

```
needles = ['//', '/']
if any(needle in str_example for needle in needles):
    do something
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are only two (possibly three) short things to check, I’d probably leave the code as it is. If something can be expressed with a short piece of very simple code, why not do that?

Four (possibly three) or more, I’d go with the `any(...)` variants that several others have already suggested.